# Canculating the compound annual growth rate

Tags: r

I'm trying to calculate the compound annual growth rate of my data (snipet shown below), does anyone know the best way to do this or if there is a function that does part of the job?

Data: (only woried about the preds column here, others can be ignored)

```
    year month timestep     ymin     ymax          preds       date
1   1998     1        1 17.84037 18.58553      18.21295 1998-01-01
2   1998     2        2 17.05009 17.70642      17.37826 1998-02-01
3   1998     3        3 16.97067 17.61320      17.29193 1998-03-01
4   1998     4        4 18.38551 19.00838      18.69695 1998-04-01
5   1998     5        5 21.39082 21.97338      21.68210 1998-05-01
6   1998     6        6 24.77679 25.35464      25.06571 1998-06-01
7   1998     7        7 27.27057 27.82818      27.54938 1998-07-01
8   1998     8        8 28.24703 28.76702      28.50702 1998-08-01
9   1998     9        9 27.72370 28.24619      27.98494 1998-09-01
10  1998    10       10 25.83783 26.33969      26.08876 1998-10-01
11  1998    11       11 22.94968 23.42268      23.18618 1998-11-01
12  1998    12       12 19.50499 20.05466      19.77982 1998-12-01
13  1999     1       13 17.98323 18.50530      18.24426 1999-01-01
14  1999     2       14 17.20124 17.61746      17.40935 1999-02-01
15  1999     3       15 17.11064 17.53492      17.32278 1999-03-01
```

Comment: If you mean the equivalent compound annual growth rate per month then it will be wildly unstable. Something like `c('', scales::percent(((tail(df$preds, -1) / head(df$preds, -1))^12 - 1), 0.1))`. If you just want a single value from the start to the end of your data, it would be `scales::percent(((tail(df$preds, 1) / head(df$preds, 1))^(12/14) - 1), 0.1)`, giving -4.2%

Comment: @AllanCameron ah yeh sorry should have been more specific, I was trying to get compound growth per annum in a 10 year period here. My data snipet doesn't make that very clear either as its just 2 years.

Comment: My second code should do the job for that Joe.

Comment: @AllanCameron Perfect. Thanks, very helpful as always